# Vout of an op-amp ever exceed gain?

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, resistors, ac

So for an opamp with a Vin of let's say 1Vpp that is amplified to 10Vpp so the gain is 10. Will Vout ever exceed 5V peak value?

Comment: That depends on input DC offset of the input signal. If it is 1Vpp over 1 VDC then output will be 10Vpp over 10 VDC.

Answer (score 1):

The Vout value can never exceed the rail voltage. So if you have ±5V rails, that will be a max value for Vout. Because of Common Mode Voltage Range (CMVR) in many opamps the output will be lower than that by a few 0.1's of a volt. (rail to rail output op amps do not have this limitation).

So if an opamp has ±5V rails with a 10Vpp signal, the most it will ever get is ±5Vpp, and if it's a sine wave it will be clipped. This is why it is important to set the gain to avoid clipping or to select the rails to be ±10V rails

Comment: So if I am amplifying a 0.5Vpp to 25Vpp which means Vout is 12.5V peak value. With my op-amp data sheet, It says with a 15V power supply, minimum output voltage swing is 10V. So am I correct to have my supply voltages at +-17.5V? I want to avoid clipping and distortions as much as possible

Comment: Post the datasheet, keep the signal to within the CMVR values (CMVR usually depends on the power rails)

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjplumh1sXqAhWZV30KHQoGCxkQFjAAegQIBRAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.st.com%2Fresource%2Fen%2Fdatasheet%2Flf351.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0JRsqjV4939kTspBMncNMG

Comment: Above is the datasheet

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Vout value can exceed the rail voltage in the case of an AC amplifier with decoupling capacitors.

These capacitors are charged through the galvanic load to some bias DC voltage (usually, Vcc/2) that is subtracted/added depending on where the load is connected:

- If the load is grounded, the bias voltage is subtracted from the output voltage and the latter can be below ground.
- If the load is connected to Vcc, the bias voltage is added to the output voltage and the latter can be above Vcc.